# ASP.NET MVC4 bundling CSS Some on CDN some local to server?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, cdn, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I am looking into the **ASP.NET MVC4 System.Web.Optimization bundling** and was wondering how would you go about serving up some **CSS files** from a **CDN** and **others local** to a server?

Is that possible?

It looks like the **bundles.UseCdn = true** is at the collection level and not a setting for an individual bundle.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct, right now the only CDN support is on a per bundle level, you cannot have a bundle with some individual assets coming from the CDN and some locally at this time.  Basically its either or: you can have the bundle use the cdn with fallback to the local server's bundle, or the entire bundle must be on the CDN.

UPDATE: But to clarify, you can have some bundles on CDN and some bundles local.  That is controlled by the CdnPath on the bundle instance.  Basically if there is no CdnPath set on an individual bundle, it will always be served locally.

Answer (score 19):

The [ASP.NET site has some information](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) about this:

> The following code replaces the local jQuery bundle with a CDN jQuery
>   bundle.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

> In the code above, jQuery will be requested from the CDN while in
>   release mode  and  the debug version of jQuery will be fetched locally
>   in debug mode. When using a CDN, you should have a fallback mechanism
>   in case the CDN request fails. The following markup fragment from the
>   end of the layout file shows script added to request jQuery should the
>   CDN fail.

Personally, I don't find myself debugging code from jQuery, Knockout, or any other library.  I always reference the CDN resource directly in my layout.  Any scripts I need to roll myself I then bundle using the MVC framework.

My sites usually look something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/content/js/siteName")
```